# JsonConvert within Quartz.net job failing

Tags: json.net, quartz.net

I have a windows service that utilizes quartz.net to compares accounts in 2 different systems on a schedule and syncs the changes from one to the other. I can not seem to get a simple rest call to work because serializing the json is failing. No exception is thrown but the json string is empty.

```
private void SendEmail(string Subject, string sBody)
{
    // Create an email message and identify the Exchange service.
    var message = new Models.EmailRequest()
    {
        // Add properties to the email message.
        Subject = "My Sync Utility: " + Subject,
        Body = sBody,
        To = "fake@fake.net",
        IsHtml = true,
        AccessCode = "1111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111"
    };
    string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
    logger.Info("JSON: " + json);
}
```

Model:

```
internal class EmailRequest
{
    public string AccessCode { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public bool IsHtml { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
}
```

This results in the log: "UserSync JSON: {} " and I can confirm this is what is reflected in the resulting string by attaching a debugger to the service. I have never seen JsonConvert fail with such a simple model before.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in a simple MCVE, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/O9Cz85.  Is there any chance that `EmailRequest` inherits from some base class marked with `[DataContract]`?

Comment: It definitely does not inherit from any base class. It works in the sample I wrote too so I wonder if it is some weird issue with calling it within a quartz.net IJob

Comment: @ChristopherKelly  Maybe.  Perhaps the framework set up a global default for `JsonSerializerSettings`.  Check the value of [`JsonConvert.DefaultSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DefaultSettings.htm) before serializing.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it turns out the problem wasn't Json.net nor Quartz but was because the obfuscator that runs post build was sealing the classes. Once I removed that flag it emailed successfully.